# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component when tried to create global component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I new on Vue Typescript. I've tried to create global components but I got a warning and component not loaded on the template. This how I tried to create global components

**App.vue**

```
import { createApp } from "vue"
import App from "./App.vue"
import "./registerServiceWorker"
import "./globalComponents"
import router from "./router"
import store from "./store"

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app")
```

**globalComponents.ts**

```
import { createApp } from "vue"

const app = createApp({})

// Forms
app.component("ui-input", () => import("@/components/core/ui/Input.vue"))
```

**Input.vue**

```
<template lang="pug">
.ui-input
  input(v-model="$attrs" v-on="$listeners")
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  inheritAttrs: false
})
</script>
```

Hope you all can help me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Vue 3, if you create an app using `createApp`, it will be a standalone Vue App instance. So if you need to add a global component then you will need to add it on the `app` object created from `createApp`, here's the code for that:

```
const app = createApp({});

app.component('my-component-name', MyComponent) // <-- here you can register.

app.mount("#app");
```

But if there are a lot of components then adding them in the `main.ts` file will be a mess, so we can create another file, like you did, so:

##### Your current `globalComponents.ts`

```
import { createApp } from "vue"

const app = createApp({})

// Forms
app.component("ui-input", () => import("@/components/core/ui/Input.vue"))
```

##### The Problem

But notice here's a mistake. What is it? You created another `app` using `createApp`. As I referred earlier that if you need to create a global component, you can only create on the same instance.

##### Fix

As we know the problem here is that we are creating another instance, which is again a new and standalone instance, so we need to figure out the way we can have the same `app` instance in `globalComponents.ts` as well, so we will pass the `app` from `main-ts` to `globalComponents.ts`, like:

##### globalComponents.ts

```
import { App } from "vue";

// register components
export const registerComponents = (app: App): void => {
    app.component("ui-input", () => import("@/components/core/ui/Input.vue"));
}
```

And now you can call `registerComponents` in `main.ts` as:

##### main.ts

```
const app = createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router);

registerComponents(app); // <-- here you go

app.mount("#app");
```

You will still get something like:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: undefined (undefined).

You can read more [here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html#_3-x-syntax) about how to define an async component in vue 3. To fix that error you will need to wrap your `import` in `defineAsyncComponent` as:

##### globalComponents.ts

```
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

// register components
export const registerComponents = (app) => {
  app.component(
    "ui-input",
    defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@/components/Input.vue"))
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi @U-Dev thanks for answer,, but sorry it still didn't work, i followed your way.. and I still got this warning

`[Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: undefined (undefined)`

Comment: WOW, Thanks a lot @U-dev ! Those are the great and right ways to do it!!

Comment: @bkndvlpr glad it helped :) And I think you are moving to vue 3 from vue 2. Assuming that I suggest you to read the vue 3 migration guide. It will help you a lot and will help in understanding vue 3 better. Here's the [link](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/introduction.html#overview)